# One API call to send SMS to multiple users (Twilio)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a list of ~50 phone numbers I need to send the same SMS to via Twilio's API. How do I do that (via Python)?

I can do it in a for loop like so:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
client = Client(SID, AT)

for number in number_list:
    client.messages.create(to=number, from_="+18328955063",body="foo bar")
```

But instead of hitting Twilio's API multiple times, I'd rather send an array/list of phone numbers in bulk and just make one API call. So how do I do that? Is it possible at all?

I'm setting up a background async task to take care of outgoing text messages, and ideally wouldn't want my task to wait a long time while Twilio processes the messages one by one. I'd just want to send over a list of numbers as payload and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can achieve this using the [Twilio Notify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest). Notify is for sending notifications to multiple platforms, but that includes SMS.

Here's how you'd do it:

First, create a [Notify service](https://www.twilio.com/console/notify/services).

Then you need to register all your users and their numbers with the Notify API by [creating bindings](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/bindings) for all of them. Each binding requires some sort of identity from your system (a user id, or similar).

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_TOKEN"
token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"
client = Client(account, token)

service = client.notify.services("YOUR_NOTIFY_SERVICE_SID")

for identity, number in user_dict.items():
    service.bindings.create(
        identity=identity,
        binding_type="sms",
        address=number
    )
```

Then, to send a notification to a group of users you just create a notification to their identities:

```
service.notifications.create(identity=list_of_identities,
                             body="Hello world!")
```

This only takes 20 identities at a time, though you can also do some work with tags when you create the bindings or [segments](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/segments-resource) to send more.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: When configuring a `Notify service`, do I need to create and select one of APN, GCM, FCM or Messaging Service SIDs? I'm unsure what this step's about.

Comment: Ah, to send SMS you'll need a [messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/services). A messaging service is basically a pool of numbers that you can send SMS from, it does other bits like geomatching phone numbers, but if you just add one number to a service then it will just act as a proxy to that number.

Comment: Hmm, when I try to register a user to a binding, I get `'Client' object has no attribute 'notify'` (my twilio package version is 6.4.1). Created a separate question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081365/error-creating-notify-service-in-twilio-python-sdk

Comment: I've answered your question :)

Comment: Just for clarification, what happens if one tries to create the same binding twice? E.g. with the same identity, but a different address? Does it get over-written automatically, or is some kind of an error code returned?

Comment: Check out this part of the documentation for all the details there: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/bindings#bindings-with-the-same-address-are-removed

Comment: I see that multiple sms sent can be done for the same body message. Is there any option for separate message per receiver?

Comment: @chatzich Not with the Notify API. To do that you will need to send one message per API request with the regular messaging API.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource#code-send-a-notification-to-bindings-in-the-request-1

```
notification = client.notify.services("ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")\
    .notifications.create(
        to_binding=[
            "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+15555555555\"}",
            "{\"binding_type\":\"facebook-messenger\",\"address\":\"123456789123\"}"
        ],
        body="Hello Bob")
```

no need to create binding,
by the way, twilio can accept 10,000 numbers

> The destination address specified as a JSON string. Multiple to_binding parameters can be included but the total size of the request entity should not exceed 1MB. This is typically sufficient for 10,000 phone numbers.