# AttributeError when creating Notify service via client.notify.services() using the Python SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to create a binding for an SMS-related notify service in Twilio (Python SDK, v 6.4.3), but it keeps giving me an `AttriuteError`. The code is simply:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
from myproj.twilio_settings import ACCNT_SID, AT, SERV_SID

client = Client(ACCNT_SID, AT)

service = client.notify.services(SERV_SID)

def bind_user_to_twilio_notify_service(user_id,phone_number):
    binding = service.bindings.create(
        identity=user_id,
        binding_type='sms',
        address=phone_number,
    )
    print(binding.sid)
```

And the error is:

> AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'notify'

Trying `service = client.notifications.v1.services(SERV_SID)` gives me

> AttributeError: 'NotificationList' object has no attribute 'v1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Notify is currently available in public beta](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/bindings) and as such it is supported only by the alpha version of helper libraries. [You'll need to install the alpha Python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python#accessing-preview-twilio-features), like:

```
pip install twilio==6.4.3a1
```

then you can use `client.notify.services(SERV_SID)`.